# Set ACL in OpenLDAP so that user can find its own entry from filtered subtree

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap, access-control-list

I have a user directory in an openldap server under the base DN `ou=users,dc=mydomain`. The user entries are `uid=user1,ou=users,dc=mydomain`

My current ACLs are:

`{5}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=mydomain" write by * none
{4}to dn.subtree="ou=users,dc=mydomain" by self read
{3}to dn.exact="dc=mydomain" attrs=entry by users search by * none
{2}to dn.base="" by * read
{1}to dn.subtree="dc=something,dc=mydomain" by dn="uid=someone,ou=users,dc=mydomain" write by * read
{0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymous auth by  dn="cn=admin,dc=mydomain" write by * none`

Those allow a user to query and find his own entry. But if the authentictated user *user1* searches for the base DN with the filter `(uid=user1)` set, no entries are found. In other words: `ldapsearch  -H ldap://myserver -b "ou=users,dc=mydomain" -D "uid=user1,ou=users,dc=mydomain" -x -W` return nothing while `ldapsearch  -H ldap://myserver -b "uid=user1,ou=users,dc=mydomain" -D "uid=user1,ou=users,dc=mydomain" -x -W` returns the entry for `user1`.

How do I need to tweak the ACLs so that the user can find his own entry (and only his own) with a filtered search on the base DN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining OpenLDAP ACLs is tricky.

Most times ACL issues are caused by processing order of ACLs themselves and 
their who-clauses (by ...) and that ACLs implicitly end with `by * none` 
stopping the control flow.

You're using dynamic configuration with *cn=config* and this uses 
*X-ORDERED* extension in the schema to preserve order of some attribute 
values like *olcAccess*.

So the order in which your ACLs are processed is:

```
{0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymous auth by  dn="cn=admin,dc=mydomain" write by * none
{1}to dn.subtree="dc=something,dc=mydomain" by dn="uid=someone,ou=users,dc=mydomain" write by * read
{2}to dn.base="" by * read
{3}to dn.exact="dc=mydomain" attrs=entry by users search by * none
{4}to dn.subtree="ou=users,dc=mydomain" by self read
{5}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=mydomain" write by * none
```

So let's look at your ACLs in detail:

`{0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymous auth by  dn="cn=admin,dc=mydomain" write by * none`

This is an rule probably taken from some default configuration.
It's ok to begin with it but I'd suggest some re-factoring:

1. Omit attribute *shadowLastChange* since LDAP shadow is broken concept. And if you do use shadow maps, this ACL would allow the user to circumvent shadow password expiry.
2. Change the order of who-clauses. In general follow the rule to mention the "higher" privileges first.
3. If cn=admin,dc=mydomain is already the *rootdn* of this database you don't need that who-clause.
4. Better grant password admin rights to a group.
5. Do not grant read privilege at all by inclusive `write` access, use write-only privilege `=w` instead.

Better use:

`{0}to attrs=userPassword by group="cn=admins,ou=groups,dc=mydomain" =w by self =w by anonymous auth by * none`

`{1}to dn.subtree="dc=something,dc=mydomain" by dn="uid=someone,ou=users,dc=mydomain" write by * read`

If `dc=mydomain` is your database suffix this ACL does not make much sense 
to me in the context of your question. Maybe a left-over from some tests?

`{2}to dn.base="" by * read`

This is not effective if placed in your database config entry. This must be 
added to front-end config entry *cn=config* (formerly in static config 
*slapd.conf* before any *database* section).

`{3}to dn.exact="dc=mydomain" attrs=entry by users search by * none`

I'd place an ACL like this at the end of the ACL list so it won't stop 
access to *entry* at this point. And if you want to use arbitrary search 
bases like *ou=users,dc=mydomain* you would have to grant this search right 
to the whole sub-tree.

So place this at the end of your ACLs and remove {3} or...

`{6}to dn.subtree="dc=mydomain" attrs=entry by users search by * none`

...move this rule:

`{4}to dn.subtree="ou=users,dc=mydomain" by self read`

Should probably be last ACL and replace {3}. See comment for {5}.

`{5}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=mydomain" write by * none`

Issues here:

1. The `by self write` will never be reach because of the `by self read` in {4}.
2. This ACL is not reached at all because of the implicit `by * none` in {4}.
3. again: granting access to *rootdn* is not necessary
4. again: better grant admin access to a group
5. use better order of who-clauses
6. reconsider if you really want to grant write access to all attributes to the user himself

Better:

`{5}to * by group="cn=admins,ou=groups,dc=mydomain" write by self write by * none`

One of the most important debugging option is to start *slapd* with logging its ACL processing:

`/usr/sbin/slapd … -d config,stats,stats2,acl`

So these hints should get you a started to work on your ACLs solving your problems yourself.
Always think twice. It seems to me you have little bit of contradictive assumptions in your rules.

But there's obviously no way around deep-diving into the docs:

If you want to understand the ACLs in detail you should consult various
  on-line documentation:

- [OpenLDAP Admin Guide -- Access control](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html)
- [slapd.access(5)](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapd.access)
- [FAQ-O-MATIC: Access Control](https://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/189.html)
- [FAQ-O-MATIC: Sets in Access Control](https://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/1133.html)

Comment: I updated my question with more details.

Comment: I've did several edits to my answer. Please read carefully.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/922829/171476) gace me the deciding clue. The only thing I had to alter was the suggested *search* acl from the top dn (dc=mydomain) to the user dn (ou=users,dc=mydomain)

Changing the ACLs to this does the trick:

`{5}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=mydomain" write by * none
{4}to dn.subtree="ou=users,dc=mydomain" by self read
{3}to dn.exact="ou=users,dc=mydomain" attrs=entry by users search by * none
{2}to dn.base="" by * read
{1}to dn.subtree="dc=something,dc=mydomain" by dn="uid=someone,ou=users,dc=mydomain" write by * read
{0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymous auth by  dn="cn=admin,dc=mydomain" write by * none`